# part of the answer in methods of undetermined coefficient I don't understand

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am working on a problem with `methods of undetermined coefficient` and I am confused when it came to the `particular solution` part

this is the D.E.

```
y'' + 3y' + 2y = x^​2
```

it goes like this...I get all this

```
Y(p)x = Ax^​2 + Bx + C
Yp' = 2Ax + B
yp'' = 2A
```

but now when it came to this part I got lost, I know it's kinda like partial fractions but how did they get this ?

```
2A + 6Ax + 3B  + 2Ax^​2+2Bx+2C= x^​2                (from here)

2Ax^​2+ (6A+2B)x+(2A+3B+2C)=1x^​2+0+0                (to here)
```

how did they get the part `2Ax^​2+ (6A+2B)x+(2A+3B+2C)` ?

Comment: Ever heard of "Collect like terms"? http://www.purplemath.com/modules/polydefs2.htm

Comment: @Amzoti done...

Comment: They are *normalizing* the LHS to  a polynomial in *standard form*, i.e. collecting together all terms with the same power of $\,x.$ This then enables one to apply the test that a polynomial $= 0$ iff its coefficient  all $= 0.$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does this help you understand?

[image]

Comment: wow!!!!!!...truly amazing..thank you much!